# OS X unable to authenticate Windows 8 share

Tags: windows, macos, mac

I recently upgraded From Windows 7 to Windows 8 and could easily connect to shared folders from my Mac OS X 10.8 macbook.

I then had to do a hard format and reinstalled Windows 8 loosing my original settings. I am now unable to authenticate to the Windows 8 machine.

On the Mac I Go > connect to server > smb://servername which gives me the dialog box for a username and password. I have tried the guest account (I have turned on guest account on the windows 8 machine) and also tried numerous of times the username and password of the 2 administrator accounts I have setup but no success.

The username and passwords are definately correct so I am not sure if I missed something on the Windows machine which could result to this. I am however able to connect to the shared drives on the Windows 8 machine from other Windows systems, it is just the Mac which does not authenticate.

Any idea where I could have missed the plot?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the share name, as suggested here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4137216?start=0&tstart=0

It looks like Mountain Lion needs a share name, whereas Lion could see all shares automatically.